# Creating training data into a TRAIN.spacy file from manually tagged data with custom entity labels

Tags: python, nlp, spacy-3

I am using spacy to build a custom NER model. I would like to create the train.spacy file using my training data. I was manually creating a list of spacy.training.Example objects but I would like to use spacy v3 training using the config files.
So I have the training data in the form of words and their corresponding labels,for multiple texts. For eg:

```
words= ['Foreign' 'broking' 'houses' 'raised' 'the' 'target' 'price' 'of'
     'Sun' 'Pharmaceutical' 'Industries,' 'Housing' 'Development' 'Finance'
     'Corporation,' 'SAIL' 'India,' 'Cholamandalam' 'Investment,' 'Sun' 'TV'
     'Network,' 'GAIL' 'India,' 'State' 'Bank' 'of' 'India' 'and' 'Eicher'
     'Motors,' 'post' 'September' 'quarter' 'earnings' 'announcement:']
entity_labels= ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ENTITY', 'I-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'B-ENTITY', 'I-ENTITY', 'I-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'B-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'B-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'B-ENTITY', 'I-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'B-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'B-ENTITY', 'I-ENTITY', 'I-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'O', 'B-ENTITY', 'L-ENTITY', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Since spacy requires training labels to be in this format

```
TRAIN_DATA=[(text,{"entities":[(start,end,label)]})]
```

Is there a quicker way to convert my data into this?The approach I am currently planning to implement is to manually go through the words and entities and get the start and end index. I would really appreciate a better way to do this though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it should be trivial to put your data in IOB/NER format, which spaCy can convert directly. See [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/extra/example_data/ner_example_data), the format is a little like this:

```
Foreign   O
broking   O
houses    O
```

> Since spacy requires training labels to be in this format

That is not correct - that format is often used for demonstration purposes, but in v3 the only requirement is that training data be saved as annotated Doc objects.

Comment: Hi!Thanks a lot!I am using the BILOU scheme for tagging and I went through the documentation and the examples. I understand now that I can use the convert command and generate training files. However, I have data stored in the BILOU tagged format in multiple csvs. Can I keep running the command and writing to the same output train.spacy file?

Comment: you can pass a directory to the convert command and it will process all the files in the dir.

Comment: This solves it. Thank you very much!